# Seeking Geodata on German Roads

Tags: geospatial, transportation, germany

I am looking for a free datasource (or a possibility to extract that data from OpenStreetMap) on Germany`s roads. I need this data for the purpose of routing/ calculating the travel distance between several points. The programs available to me are QGIS, ArcGIS and R Studio. Unfortunately, I do not know python language, thus the geodata should be readable in one of those programs for the purpose of my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start with https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html. You can download the `.pbf` files and import lines & multilinestrings into your GIS software (at least QGIS). In OSM roads have a `key = highway`. For details please check https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highway. In `R` you can use `osmdata` library to access the data via Overpass.