# Seeking toutable file of German Road System

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, germany

I am looking for a routable file of the German Road System in order to perform route calculation in QGIS, ArcGIS Desktop or even R Studio.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeking Geodata on German Roads](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20115/seeking-geodata-on-german-roads)

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not seing that there are no suggestions on this post either.